# Can you mount AWS EFS from a HP-unix system?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-efs

We have an EFS server in our AWS account currently mounted on all our dev systems(RHEL 8.1) in the same VPC and it is working fine. Recently we received a request to mount this EFS server from a on premise server running on HP-unix. On-prem network and aws are connected via  Direct connect. I have tried all usual setting changes like allowing on-prem IP range in EFS SG, allowing UDP-2049 in EFS SG etc. Nothing works.
Below is a sample error from HP-ux system:

#mount -F nfs3 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport X.X.X.X:/ /
mount: cannot access nfs3-specific mount command

While reading AWS documentation on EFS, I came across this statement: "Your on-premises server must have a Linux-based operating system. We recommend Linux kernel version 4.0 or later." (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/how-it-works.html)

Is there a way to mount EFS on a HP-UX on-prem server connected via Direct connect to AWS?

Comment: does this help https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/efs-onpremises.html and this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-efs-update-on-premises-access-via-direct-connect-vpc/

Comment: I have checked both of these links and nowhere it mentions that it is possible from a HP-ux system. It lists Amazon linux/2, RHEL, CentOS and Ubuntu as supported distributions. This documentation on AWS says the following: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/how-it-works.html Your on-premises server must have a Linux-based operating system. We recommend Linux kernel version 4.0 or later.